# GstOverlay and gtk : Display without padding (Black strips)

Tags: c++, gtk, gstreamer, wxwidgets

I render my streaming in a wxWidget ImagePanel (`m_renderwindow` in my code) like in the picture : [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4n3X.jpg). The problem is that I have padding at top and bottom and I don't succeed to remove it. I Try `gst_video_overlay_set_render_rectangle` but the area stay black and don't display the stream. Does anyone have an idea?

```
    GstState state;
    GstState pending;
    GstPad* pad = nullptr;
    GError* error = NULL;
    GstElement* source;
    GstElement* clocktime;
    GstElement* textoverlay;
    GstCaps* caps = gst_caps_new_simple("application/x-rtp",
        "media", G_TYPE_STRING, "video",
        "payload", G_TYPE_INT, 96,
        "encoding-name", G_TYPE_STRING, "H264",
        NULL);

    (*ptrstats).pipeline = gst_parse_launch("udpsrc name=source !rtph264depay !h264parse !avdec_h264 ! videoconvert !d3dvideosink name=mysink sync=false ", &error);

    if (!(*ptrstats).pipeline) {
        outfile << "Load video : ", error->message, "\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    source = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN((*ptrstats).pipeline), "source");
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(source), "caps", caps, NULL);
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(source), "port", m_port, NULL);

    pad = gst_element_get_static_pad(source, "src");
    gst_pad_add_probe(pad, GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BUFFER, (GstPadProbeCallback)buffer_out_cb, ptrstats, NULL);
    gst_object_unref(pad);

#ifdef __WXGTK__
    outfile << "__WXGTK__\n";
    GstElement* sink = gst_bin_get_by_name((GstBin*)(*ptrstats).pipeline, "mysink");
    gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle(GST_VIDEO_OVERLAY(sink), m_xid);
#elif defined __WXMSW__
    GstElement* sink = gst_bin_get_by_name((GstBin*)(*ptrstats).pipeline, "mysink");
    WXWidget hwnd = m_renderWindow->GetHandle();
    //gst_video_overlay_set_render_rectangle(GST_VIDEO_OVERLAY(sink), 0, 0, 1224, 1024);
    gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle(GST_VIDEO_OVERLAY(sink),
        reinterpret_cast<guintptr>(hwnd));
#endif
    

    gst_element_set_state((*ptrstats).pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
```

SOLUTION : add d3dvideosink force-aspect-ratio=false

Comment: What are you referring to by "padding"? The black strips from the rendered image, or the grey ones from `ImagePanel`?

Comment: Yes I mean the black strips at the top and bottom

Comment: Try setting `d3dvideosink force-aspect-ratio=false` if you don't care that the picture has the correct aspect ratio.

Comment: @FlorianZwoch Thank you it solves my problem